# make individual items in listbox selectable

Tags: wpf

I have a listbox where some items should be selectable and others shouldn't be selectable.

The listbox uses a datatemplate and has animations that are initiated with triggers. I can set an attached property on listboxItem to do this but I'm at a loss as how to do this in a datatemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ItemContainerStyle` to bind `IsEnabled` for example.